# Would utilizing the word "display" in the following sentence be acceptable?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

My father doesn't **display** it in public.

For some context, the conversation was about my father's lack to **show** certain emotion.

Would it be more appropriate to use:
My father doesn't **portray** it in public.

I greatly appreciate any and all assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Display" sounds as if it is likely to be correct. One speaks of displaying various emotions when one means simply that the emotion that the person is experiencing is also visible to others. "Portray" implies that the emotion is not one that is necessarily being experienced. An actor in a film or on stage might "portray" feelings of anger without actually being enraged.